# TextSize Dynamic Adaptation Issue in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, xml

I'm encountering an issue in my Android Studio project related to TextView rendering within a ConstraintLayout . The goal is to make the text fill the available space dynamically , adapting to various screen ratios without specifying a fixed text size . I've included a snippet of my XML layout file below :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/start_step_txt_v"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3241" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/end_step_txt_v"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8389" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/start_step_txt_h"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5045" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/end_step_txt_h"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5482" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nb_steps"
    style="@style/steps_and_workout_today_username_profil_MB_80_W_second_menus_shop_workouts_date_calender_label_set_rep_exercice_noun_info"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/none"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/none"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/end_step_txt_h"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/end_step_txt_v"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/start_step_txt_v"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/start_step_txt_h"
    android:elevation="@dimen/med_elevation"
    android:text="@string/Nb_steps" />
```

I've set `@dimen/none` to 0dp and defined only color and font type in the style. Despite these adjustments, the text size doesn't dynamically adapt as intended. I would appreciate guidance on achieving dynamic text size adjustment based on different screen ratios without specifying a fixed size. Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you really want to adapt? The **TextView** size as mentioned in your title, or the **text** size as mentioned in your text?

Comment: @Cloverleaf I want to adapt the font size of the text (textsize) but I thought that by adapting the textview the textize would automatically adapt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From API 26, the default `TextView` already provides the api to auto-sizing the font size:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
    android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp" />
```

Checkout this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/text-and-emoji/autosizing-textview)

Comment: When I initiated the project, I opted for API 21 (Android 5.0) to ensure compatibility with a wide range of devices. However, it seems that this specific functionality requires a minimum API level of 26, which could be the reason it's not working for me.

Comment: Well then I just think of using scale animation for this case, it may break the pixel when scaling up but may work. But you should consider upgrading the minimum version too because Android 8 launched 5 years ago and already covered 95% of devices so it is pretty standard now. Check this report: https://apilevels.com/

Comment: So the best solution is to upgrade to android 8 (API 26) to have something clean ?

Comment: It is just my recommendation, not the best one but it can be done with no impact to most users IMHO. You have the most latest API from Android, officially supported for auto-sizing `TextView`, and 95% of users are not impacted, which to me is a good trade-off. Just double-check with your analytics data, recent active devices within 6 months, what percent of devices are lower than API 26, and make your decision.

Comment: Yes, I believe it's a wise decision to transition to API 26 in order to access these additional features without a significant impact on user base. Thank you very much for your guidance and assistance !

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your activity:

```java
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.nb_steps);
String futureText = "(your text)";

// Calculate the width of the TextView in pixels given by the Guidelines
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
float tvGivenWidth = (0.8389f-0.3241f)*displayMetrics.widthPixels;

// Calculate the width of the TextView with setTextSize(18) and futureText
tv.setTextSize(18);
float tv18Width = tv.getPaint().measureText(futureText, 0, futureText.length());

// Use a rule of proportion to calculate the text size that just fills the given space.
// Reduce the value by 1% due to rounding errors etc.
tv.setTextSize(0.99f*18f*tvGivenWidth/tv18Width);
tv.setText(futureText);
```

You must choose a sufficiently large distance between the horizontal GuideLines, otherwise you will have to make the same considerations for the vertical extension.

**UPDATE:**

As of API30, the calculation of the screen width is deprecated. Use this code instead:

```java
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
WindowMetrics metrics = wm.getCurrentWindowMetrics();
float tvGivenWidth = (0.8389f-0.3241f)*metrics.getBounds().width();
```

Comment: Can you explain further ?

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: It's okay, I've grasped the code, but I'm curious about the most optimal approach: using your method or employing `android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` in XML ?

Comment: between, I noticed that some of the methods I used, such as getMetrics and defaultDisplay, are marked as deprecated with the message 'Deprecated in Java.' I wanted to check with you if there's a more up-to-date approach or if these deprecations can be safely ignored for now. Your insights are highly appreciated !

Comment: I added the case `API>=30` in my answer. The best solution to your problem would be a case distinction with both suggestions: `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {use my solution} else {use solution with autoSizeTextType="uniform"}`.